# PHP download gives me empty pdf

Tags: php, pdf, download

```
$file = "http://www.abax.se/content/download/137/862/file/example.pdf";
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
flush();
readfile($file);
```

This is the code I'm running, I'm out of ideas, any solution?

Comment: Same thing, empty downloaded pdf...

Comment: This code looks odd. Why are you downloading a file in order to upload it? Why do you not just send a "301 Moved Permanently" response, sending the user directly to the file? Is the file on the same server as this code? If so then you should not go through HTTP; you should just read and output the file directly from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));`.

Thats what's breaking your output.

`filesize()` expects a local file, not an url.

Working code:

```
<?php
$file = "http://www.abax.se/content/download/137/862/file/example.pdf";
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
flush();
readfile($file);
?>
```

Comment: "Failed to load PDF documnet"

Comment: Added the working code to the answer. This is working fine on php5.4.